# How to generate the python files using antlr v4 plugin in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr

when clicking on "generate ANTLR recognizer" its only generating the java files and I'm not able to find how to generate python files instead of java files.

Comment: What plugin is in use? Is it https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4/ ?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov yes sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `language=...;` to the `options { ... }` of your grammar:

```
grammar Test;

options {
  language=Python3;
}

parse
 : ANY*? EOF
 ;

ANY
 : .
 ;
```

Or right click the grammar and choose the option `Configure ANTLR...`, and then set the language property in there.